# Is it possible to secure a ColdFusion 11 REST Service with HTTP BASIC Authentication?

Tags: rest, authentication, iis, coldfusion

I am setting up a simple REST Service in ColdFusion 11. The web server is IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012R2.

This REST Service needs to be secured to prevent unauthorized users from accessing/writing data. For the time being, there will be only one authorized user, so I want to keep authentication/authorization as simple as possible. My initial thought is to use HTTP BASIC Authentication.

Here's the setup for the REST Service:

Source Directory: C:\web\site1\remoteapi\
REST path: inventory

To implement this, I configured the source directory of the REST Service in IIS to authorize only one user, disable Anonymous authentication, and enable Basic authentication.

When I call the source directory directly in a browser (i.e. http://site1/remoteapi/inventory.cfc?method=read), I am presented with the Basic authentication dialog.

However, when I attempt to request the REST path (http://site1/rest/inventory/), I am not challenged at all.

How can I implement HTTP BASIC authentication on the REST path?

Comment: Don't really have an answer but I believe the issue is that the IIS security is set on the folder `C:\web\site1\remoteapi\ ` but the REST path is actually `//site1/rest/inventory/ ` which doesn't really exist in the IIS realm. So the authentication challenge isn't happening. I don't think you can create a virtual directory in IIS to resolve this as that would catch the request before ColdFusion. Can you move the IIS security up to the web root and try that?  Otherwise my only other thought is to handle the challenge with ColdFusion (have it send 401) but I would prefer the web server to do it.

Comment: @Miguel-F yes, that's my assumption too. I would like the web server to authenticate the user as well. I'm working on a way to handle the authentication in CF...

Answer (score 1):

So, due to the need to get this done without much delay, I went ahead and using some principles from Ben Nadel's website, I wrote my own authentication into the onRequestStart() method of the REST Service's Application.cfc. Here is the basic code, though it uses hard-coded values in the VARIABLES scope to validate the username and password and also does not include any actual "authorization" setting:

```
public boolean function onRequestStart(required string targetPage) {
    LOCAL.Response = SUPER.onRequestStart(ARGUMENTS.targetpage);

    if  (!StructKeyExists(GetHTTPRequestData().Headers, "Authorization")) {
        cfheader(
            name="WWW-Authenticate",
            value="Basic realm=""REST API Access"""
            );

        LOCAL.RESTResponse = {
            status = 401,
            content = {Message = "Unauthorized"}
            };

        restSetResponse(LOCAL.RESTResponse);
    }
    else {
        LOCAL.IsAuthenticated = true;

        LOCAL.EncodedCredentials =
            GetToken( GetHTTPRequestData().Headers.Authorization, 2, " " );

        //  Credential string is not Base64
        if  (   !ArrayLen(
                    REMatch(
                        "^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$",
                        LOCAL.EncodedCredentials
                        )
                    )
            ) {
            LOCAL.IsAuthenticated = false;
        }
        else {
            //  Convert Base64 to String
            LOCAL.Credentials =
                ToString(ToBinary( LOCAL.EncodedCredentials ));

            LOCAL.Username = GetToken( LOCAL.Credentials, 1, ":" );
            LOCAL.Password = GetToken( LOCAL.Credentials, 2, ":" );

            if  (   LOCAL.Username != VARIABLES.CREDENTIALS.Username
                ||  LOCAL.Password != VARIABLES.CREDENTIALS.Password
                ) {
                LOCAL.IsAuthenticated = false;
            }
        }

        if  (!LOCAL.IsAuthenticated) {
            LOCAL.Response = {
                status = 403,
                content = {Message = "Forbidden"}
                };

            restSetResponse(LOCAL.Response);
        }
    }

    return LOCAL.Response;
}
```